# GitHub で PHP の書き方の見本となるようなコードを探すには？

Tags: php, github

上級プログラマーから評価されるようなコードを作っていきたいと考えており、お手本になるようなコードをGitHubで探しておりますが、中々見つかりません。

言語はPHPで、以下のようなコードを探しております。

・可読性が高い
・保守性が高い
・コメントが適切（出来れば日本語）
・無駄のないコード

ご存じであれば、教えて頂きたいです。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: あなた自身はどのような方法で探したかを記載しておくと、別の方法を提案しやすくなるかもしれません。

Comment: あなたにとって見本となるようなコードと、読者にとって見本になるようなコードはたぶん違うでしょう。読者が良いと思ったコードを紹介しても無駄に終わる可能性が高いかも。

Comment: コメント頂き、ありがとうございます。探しました方法はGitHubの詳細検索で、php、スターが多い順などで検索し、参考になりそうなリポジトリを順番に見ている状態です。　GitHubにあげているコードが評価され、内定を取った方がおられれば、他者に評価されたコードになりますので、ご参考までにお見せいただきたいです。

Comment: 「おすすめのコードを教えてください」だと、いわゆる買い物リスト型の質問となってしまいこちらのサイトではオフトピックになるでしょう。詳しくは[こちら](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1381)で